# Sharepoint 2013 sites doesn't open

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

When I open my site on SharePoint 2013 with SharePoint designer I'm getting the follow error.

> The webserver at `http://....` does not appear to have Microsoft SharePoint Foundation installed.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to open the site using Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes I can open site on Internet Explorer, but I can't open Sharepoint Designer

Comment: I restarted site, on IIS. Then this issue solved. Thanks for interest @AmalHashim

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `Client Integration` is not enabled.

Follow steps

1. Open Central Administration -> Security.
2. Click Specify authentication providers.
3. If the Web application in the Web Application list is not the same application that you want to open in SharePoint Designer, click Web Application on the Change Web Application list.
4. On the Select Web Application page, click the name of the Web application that you want to open.
5. Under Zone, Click Default to open the Edit Authentication page.
6. Under Enable Client Integration, click Yes, and then click Save.

Reset the IIS -> Close SharePoint Designer -> Start and try again.